# Input button does not work in my shiny app

Tags: html, r, button, shiny

I created a shiny app. But the input button is not reactive.
Here is a snapshot of the code:

**server:**

```
  A<-reactive({
    x<-input$RunModel
    quit()##Their is another function here, i wrote quit() just for ilustration
  })
```

**HTML:**

```
    <INPUT style="background-color:#143d4d;color:white;" onclick="newDoc(this.value)" TYPE="button" id="RunModel" class="btn btn-primary" VALUE="Run Model"/>
```

But unfortunately this button is not reactive.  I searched on the web and I found that it should work.  What happened?

Comment: It would help everyone if you would provide the URLs for what you found online that guided you.

Comment: @lawyeR yes, i did inspect element to the examples in http://shiny.rstudio.com/.  inspect element, because i write in html style.

Comment: What if you add `return(x)` right before closing `})`.

Comment: @flamenco I tried this, it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out how to do it.

with `observeEvent` method. here is a snapshot of the code:

```
  observeEvent(input$RunModel,label ="Write a label for debugging",function() {
   quit()
  })
```

Now when i click the 'RunModel' button it will active the `observeEvent`.
And quit the app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your reactive is , you not returning any value.When you press "input" button of your app, it must be returning some value to be displayed. Give that value in return of reactive
Sahring some part of server.r:

```
contentInput <- reactive({ 

write your Logic/Program

return(xyz)
 })

output$content <- renderGvis({
 temp <- contentInput
  gvisTable(tmp)
 })
```